# Automate upgrade of TFS Build servers on custom directory

Tags: tfs

The procedure for unattended configuration is well defined ([Unattended Install of TFS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsao/archive/2012/10/01/unattended-installation-of-tfs-2012.aspx)), while the setup part is obscure at best. The only known command is

> tfs_server.exe /quiet

but there is no way to specify a different installation folder.

I have tens of build servers to upgrade from 2012.4 to 2013, and need to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this response on Visual Studio official forum.

*For the specify different installation folder in unattended installation scenario, please submit it to User Voice site at: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. Microsoft engineers will evaluate them seriously.*

In other words, it is not possible with current installer, i.e. TFS 2013.